# globaltoLocal in addchild

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addchild

I have an enemy that adds an attack movie clip. More specifically, this attack movie (We'll call it masterAttack) clip is a blank movie clip that acts like a super class, that will hold other attacks like a weak and strong attack. So when my enemy attacks using a timer, it adds the masterAttack on a global to local point.

Below is the Enemy timer attacking a tile the player is on:

```
if (Main.tileset[k].tileMiddle.hitTestObject(Main.player.visionPoint))
{
         this.addChild(masterAttack);
         var pt:Point = this.enemymagic.globalToLocal(new Point(Main.tileset[k].x, Main.tileset[k].y));
         masterAttack.masterEnemyAttackTimer.start();

         this.masterAttack.x = (pt.x);
         this.masterAttack.y = (pt.y);
}
```

And Below is the masterAttack timer:

```
function mastertimer(event:TimerEvent) {
                    addChild(sludgeball); //This is one of the many attacks pickable by the masterAttack
                              sludgeball.enemyattackTimer.start();
                              if (this.sludgeball.currentLabel == "End") {
                                        this.sludgeball.gotoAndPlay(1);
                                        masterEnemyAttackTimer.stop();

                              if (masterEnemyAttackTimer.running == false)
                              {
                                        attackStop = true;
                                        this.parent.removeChild(this);
                                        removeChild(sludgeball);
                              }
                    }
```

My problem is, on the first run, the masterAttack will attack the player wherever it is, then remove itself, which is good. Then the next time it runs,  the masterAttack is not hitting the player. It's as if the globaltoLocal isn't working after the first run.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.addChild(masterAttack);

var pt:Point = this.enemymagic.globalToLocal(new Point(Main.tileset[k].x, Main.tileset[k].y));
```

You add the masterAttack to this, but you got pt using enemymagic's globalToLocal

So change the line like this

```
var pt:Point = this.globalToLocal(new Point(Main.tileset[k].x, Main.tileset[k].y));
```

Comment: Oops sorry. I changed it to masterAttack just for the sake of an example. The first code, which is in the enemy, is running via a timer.

Comment: So I am removing the enemymagic/masterAttack from the pt var. I'll give it a try. Thanks.